# Como obtener variables de entorno de windows con javascript

Tags: javascript, windows

Como podria obtener desde el lado del cliente ciertas variables de entorno de windows, como el usuario de inicio de sesion  con javascript ( sin ningun framwork)

que no sea con activexobject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript, o mejor, el navegador, no tiene permisos para acceder a las variables de entorno/sistema.

Imagínate lo que podría pasar si cualquier pagina web pudiera acceder a tus variables, cualquier ladrón podría **obtener información sensible** sobre tu ordenador.

Aunque también podrías utilizar [node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js), un "navegador" especial, pero probablemente nadie de tus visitas lo utilice.

En un navegador normal, no hay manera de conseguir las variables de entorno solo con Javascript.